# How can I handle an error of VS Code: Port 5500+?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

First time for using [VS CODE](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and I was studying and would like to do the same things like video until I got an error of extension **Live Server (5500+)**. Actually the browser was still running normally but the error still appeared. Were that be a error and how can I handle that.

I am so graceful for receiving the answers, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the `Live Server` extension if you are not using the extension.
The Live Server extension uses port 5500.

Comment: Live Server's very useful. I think I'll keep it on. Thanks